# How to create and pass a parameter between macros in Acess 2003?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

Is there a way to create a parameter and pass it to a variety of macros? As I know there is no `SetTempVar` action in Access 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest would probably be to use a form - it can be hidden, or the tag property of the current form if all macros are to be run with respect to a single form.

Answer (score 1):

A good way for this is to use a public variable, this could then be referenced from forms, procedures, or macro's.

Create a blank module and declare a variant as follows:

```
Public varParameter As Variant
```

If you are using the same data types then you could declare as is but Variant is open to accepting all formats.

Comment: How would you use this with a macro? I think you would have to create two functions to use it, and then check that the data type is right,  which could make it more complicated than a form.

Comment: It would really depend on the exact setup of the macro's and whether you were looking to specify the value each time you ran through or whether you wanted to set a permanent value in place, if that was the case then you could amend my line slightly to: Public Const varParameter As Variant = "Green" for example if green was your parameter

Comment: Matt It is not possible to refer to a variable in a macro, even to a public variable.

Comment: I may be confusing myself with VBA to be honest, I try to avoid macro's when I can, if I knew exactly what the macro's were being used for I may be able to comment further